# Changing incoming call screen title - Android Studio Broadcast receiver

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

Community i wish you all are fine. I was wondering is there any way to over ride the phone number on incoming call screen of android phones. In broadcast listener we can get the phone number but is there any way to change the phone number on incoming call screen with custom text? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: unless you're willing to write your own dialer it's not gonna be possible

Comment: Yes you are right , i searched it too and came to know its not possible, but it is really hectic to write own dialer just to perform one little thing